# ng-virtual-keyboard not working with ionic modal

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, keyboard

I am trying to implement virtual keyboard in ionic modal input. For that I'm using this library, which is based on jQuery based Mottie Keyboard, [ng-virtual-keyboard](https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard). I've implemented this in my code, but when I use it with ionic modal input, keyboard is visible, but unable to click.i.e, when I click on the virtual keyboard, area beneath it get clicked.

I've included all the specified scripts, here is my code

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/keyboard/dist/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/keyboard/dist/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-virtual-keyboard/dist/ng-virtual-keyboard.min.js"></script>
```

And when the modal is shown, I'm doing this

```
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
    $('.modal input').each(function() {
        $(this).data('keyboard').destroy();
    });
});

$scope.$on('modal.shown', function(event) {
    // Execute action
    var asdf = $('.modal input').keyboard();
    $('.modal input').keyboard({
      layout: 'qwerty',
      usePreview: false
    })
    // activate the typing extension
    .addTyping({
      showTyping: true,
      delay: 50
    });
});
```

[image]
I tried everything I can to fix this, can anyone please suggest some fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding the css property `pointer-events: auto;` to the popup.

This is how the new code looks like

In HTML,

```
<input type="search" ng-model="searchText" ng-virtual-keyboard="kb_config">
```

In controller,

```
$scope.kb_config={
    layout: 'qwerty',
    usePreview: false,
    autoAccept: true,
    autoUpdateModel: true,
    css:{popup:'aiv-keyboard'}
}
```

and in css,

```
.aiv-keyboard{
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```